# Do I need to redeploy all firebase functions each time I update a const?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a firebase function to work with the SendGrid api. I'm testing multiple API keys so I need to change them back in forth. My code is setup as follows:

```
const SEND_GRID_KEY = "HIDDEN"
exports.getSendGridLists = functions.https.onCall(async () => {
  const axios = require('axios');
  var options = { method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/lists',
    qs: { page_size: '100' },
    headers: { authorization: 'Bearer ' + SEND_GRID_KEY },
    body: '{}' };
  await axios(options)
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      console.log(response.body);
  })
});
```

When I update SEND_GRID_KEY's value Do I need to redeploy all functions since the const declaration lies outside the function (firebase deploy --only functions) or can I just push the individual function (firebase deploy --only functions:getSendGridLists)?

Comment: you can use runtime configs to store api keys. when you deploy one function, it'll update runtime configs.(js or json I don't remember exactly). No need to update all functions

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to change the behavior of one function, it's only necessary to deploy that one function.  The code of the entire project is copied for each function, and each function runs completely independently of each other - they do not share anything in memory at runtime.

Comment: Would this also be true if `SEND_GRID_KEY` was imported from another file?

Comment: As I said, "The code of the entire project is copied for each function".  It doesn't matter which file.  Everything is copied.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be changing SEND_GRID_KEY often, I suggest you store it in Firestore, and instruct your function to fetch the value from Firestore instead of from the *const*.

That way, you can just login to your Firebase console, and change the value in Firestore user interface manually. No need to redeploy anything.

Of course, since this is sensitive data, make sure that you're the only one who can read/write the collection/document in which you're going to store that value. You can make sure of that, using Firestore rules.